# Highlight any data value in a column that is repeated a certain number of times

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

Is it possible to use conditional formatting to highlight any non specific value if it is repeated a certain number of times in a single column?

Basically what I want the sheet to do is highlight the value if it is repeated less than or greater than six times in a column. Is this possible using conditional formatting or any other way? Any help would be appreciated.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqekx.png)

Comment: Assuming data starts in A1 as shown in your example, select cell A1 and create a conditional format rule with this formula: `=AND(COUNTIF(A:A,A1)<>6,A1<>"")` and then apply to column A:A

Comment: @tigeravatar Works perfect. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Copied from a [Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49016509/highlight-any-data-value-in-a-column-that-is-repeated-a-certain-number-of-times#comment85038220_49016509):

> Assuming data starts in A1 as shown in your example, select cell A1 and create a conditional format rule with this formula: `=AND(COUNTIF(A:A,A1)<>6,A1<>"")` and then apply to column A:A – tigeravatar Feb 27 at 19:38